# A Shorter Zero Vector

Tags: vertical-alignment, vector, overset

I'm looking for a nice 0 vector for some linear algebra flashcards utilizing MathJax. I know some conventions use theta, but I find that practice very confusing.

At the current moment I'm using `\vec{0}`, but due to the height of zero the vector makes the character too tall.

Is there a shorter zero (but taller than a lowercase o) that I can use to make the zero vector more visually appealing?

Comment: Perhaps `\mathbf{0}`?

Comment: Mmm interesting. Can't decide if this is an improvement or not. Certainly an improvement over `\mathit{0}` which is barely different from regular 0.

Comment: Makes sense if you follow ISO style: bold constants, upright vectors, bold upright constant vectors.

Comment: *If* you *really* think it makes sense to denote certain vectors differently, why not $\boldsymbol{0}$. *However*, already the real numbers form a vector space, so numbers *are* vectors. Would you think of indicating that, say, 1.7 is a vector by writing $\vec{1.7}$ or $\boldsymbol{1.7}$? No? See, that's why I dare to predict that your desire to indicate vectors typographically will decline, as it did for most of us. Of course, this is a LaTeX and not a maths site, so you can of course ignore all this, but nevertheless....

Comment: @marmot The product by the vector zero or the scalar zero could be very different, although I would not depend on font weight alone to disambiguate between scalar multiplication and the dot product.

Comment: @marmot Thanks! I edited in your suggestion from the comments, which could be better if the font uses oldstyle numbers.

Comment: @Davislor And when you go relativistic, you have 4-vectors, and not too many type them boldface. Let's clean up here?

Comment: @marmot It’s true that the reals form a vector space, but I personally have never seen anyone use vector notation for that.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, that's precisely the point. If you don't use this notation for some vectors, why using it for any of them?

Comment: @marmot This is getting a bit off-topic, but: if your scalars and vectors are the same set, then they’re interchangeable. If not, which is almost always the case, you use a different notation to stop yourself from writing nonsense. I’m used to strong typing and operator overloading from programming languages, so it makes sense to me to use the same approach. (I still remember getting back a note from a prof as an undergrad: “Dividing by a vector?” That was embarrassing.) Worse, the dot product operation becomes ambiguous.

Comment: @marmot When doing flashcards across many different math fields, I want a high amount of specificity because the cards cover a lot of fields. The more intuitive I can make the notation for myself the less I'm thinking about the notation and the faster I'm memorizing important theorems and concepts. If I were a linear algebraist I suspect I'd very quickly drop denoting every vector with `\vec`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could follow [ISO style](https://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf) and use `\mathbf{0}` for **0**.   That is, bold vectors, upright constants, bold upright constant vectors.

Alternatives include `\boldsymbol{0}` from `amsmath` and `\symbfup{0}` from `unicode-math` (which also supports the previous two).

It might be a good idea to `\DeclareRobustCommand\zerovec{\mathbf{0}}` so you can try different definitions out or change to another package.

Comment: I think I may go this direction. Do you know where I might access a more complete style guide?

Comment: Here is an [older one from the TeX Users Group](https://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf). Today, I’d recommend `\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}` to use ISO style in new documents. Note that these conventions are more common in physics than in pure mathematics.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The examples there should still work today. If you’re using `unicode-math`, you can make the following improvements: use `\symup` instead of `\mathrm` for upright symbols (what the article calls “Roman”), `\symbfup` for bold upright, `\symbfit` for bold slanted, and `\symit` if you want to specify the default italic. This allows you to load your math letters from a different font; for example, from a sans-serif font for legibility.

Answer (score 3):

Here, I just make the `0` in `\scriptstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\{\vec{\scriptstyle 0}\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is in honor of the founder of the `scalerel` package. You can get the size of your zero as you wish by changing the parameter of the first part of `\scaleobj{1}`{.....}.
I then used another package called `esvect` (for the notation of the vector arrows that I love). In this case I have not used `[d]` which is the default notation but `[b]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
$\{\vv{\scaleobj{1}{0}}\}$,  $\{\vv{\scaleobj{.5}{0}}\}$, $\{\vv{\scaleobj{.7}{0}}\}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I may use this later. But because of the nature of the MathJax I'm trying to avoid any unnecessary packages to avoid the slowing down of flashcards loading. Even small slowdowns become tiresome when repeatedly doing flashcards.

Comment: @MarcusHelmer I know MathJax, but I'm not an expert. I've put an alternative code so you can try it. My best regards.